# Incompatible types error with Map

Tags: java, generics

Here is an example of the code that has been confusing me.

If I try to create a collection of a bounded type and assign the same variable to another variable that is another collection of unbounded unknown type, the code works.

```
List<? extends Number> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
List<?> anotherList = numberList; // OK
```

If I try to do the same inside a Map I get the "incompatible types" error.

```
Map<String, List<? extends Number>> numberMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, List<?>> anotherMap = numberMap; // ERROR
```

The error says:

```
Map<String,List<? extends Number>> cannot be converted to Map<String,List<?>>
```

Isn't `Map<String,List<? extends Number>>` a type of `Map<String,List<?>>`?

Here's the whole class for your convenience https://ideone.com/AZgV9H

I'm trying to understand why this isn't working and how should I change it in order to make it work.

Comment: Generics are **not** covariant. Just like a `List<String>` is not a `List<Number>`, a `Map<X, List<? extends Y>>`is not a `Map<X, ?>`.

Comment: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because a `List<? extends Number>` is a subtype of `List<?>` doesn't mean that `Map<String, List<? extends Number>>` is a subtype of `Map<String, List<?>>` for the same reason that a `List<Number>` is not a subtype of `List<?>` -- Java's generics are invariant.

To get `List<Number>` to be a subtype of `List<?>`, you had to add the wildcard with a bound.  The solution is the same here -- add `? extends` to `List<?>`.

```
Map<String, ? extends List<?>> anotherMap = numberMap;
```